# PHP Delete Array Element if Match in File on Post

Tags: php, jquery

I believe this is pretty close but I keep getting a 500 error.  I have an html form where you type in an e-mail and then it posts to a file called unsubscribe.php which is suppose to find a match and then remove it from the file. Where am I going wrong? It can tell you if someone is in the file but the issue is with deleting the matching record.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $file = file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/subscribers.php');
        $file = explode(', ', $file);

        if (in_array($email, $file)) {
            $fopen = fopen(__DIR__.'/subscribers.php', 'r+');
            if(($key = array_search($email, $file)) !== false) {
                unset($file[$key]);
                fwrite($fopen, $file);
                fnclose($fopen);
                echo "successfully unsubscribed ${email}";
            }
            echo "error unsubscribing ${email}";
        } else {
            echo "no matching email found";
        }
    } else {
        echo "email address invalid";
    }
}
?>

    //unsubscription action
    $('#submit0').click(function () {
        var email = $('#email0').val().toLowerCase();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'unsubscribe.php',
            data: {email: email},
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result0').hide();
                $('#result0').html(data);
                $('#result0').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is there a error report in the logs?

Comment: `fwrite($fopen, $file);` is wrong. `$file` is an array, the second argument to `fwrite()` should be a string. It should be `fwrite($fopen, implode(', ', $file));`

Comment: But the fatal error is because of `fnclose($fopen)`. The name of the function is `fclose()`.

Comment: with the above example I get a POST unsubscribe 500 error

Comment: Why don't you just use `file_put_contents()` instead of `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fclose()`?

Comment: @Xeverus You have to check the log on the server, it explains what caused the 500 error.

Comment: So the errors are gone but it still doesn't remove the matching email in the subscribers.php file. No errors though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in `fnclose`, it should be `fclose`. But a better way is to use `file_put_contents`.

Also, you need to call `implode()` to convert `$file` back to a string. And the error message should be in an `else` statement.

You don't need to use both `in_array()` and `array_search()`.

```
        if if(($key = array_search($email, $file)) !== false) {
            unset($file[$key]);
            if (file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/subscribers.php', implode(', ', $file))) {
                echo "successfully unsubscribed ${email}";
            } else {
                echo "error unsubscribing ${email}";
            }
        } else {
            echo "no matching email found";
        }
```

Comment: There are no errors and it returns successfully unsubscribed but doesn't remove the matching record in the subscribers.php file.

Comment: If you've run the script before, it has probably corrupted the file. When you forgot to use `implode()`, it replaced the file contents with the word `Array`.

Comment: I thought so too - but just the right contents " , test@gmal.com, "

Comment: What email did you try to remove? Notice that you have a typo in `gmal`, it's not `gmail`

Comment: the email is the right now - new keyboard keep missing keys - the file contains , test@gmail.com, and when I action the unsubscribe button with test@gmail.com in it - it successfully unsubscribes but doesn't remove the email from the file.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally removed the code that set `$key`.